# ldap connection with switch HP 5700 flexFabric

Tags: ldap, hp, switch

Can I restrict ssh login access to my HP Switch 5700, 5800 series using active directory groups?

ldap is working fine when the search-base-dn is using an **OrganisationUnit**.

```
search-base-dn OU=privilegedUser,OU=User,DC=company,DC=com
```

Using a global **group with typ security** is not working.

```
search-base-dn CN=switch-admins,OU=groups,OU=User,DC=company,DC=com
```

Syntax:

```
system-view
ldap server domain_name
search-base-dn OU=privilegedUser,OU=User,DC=company,DC=com
```

Syntax 2:

I also tried to accomplish the filtering with:

```
system-view
ldap server domain_name
search-base-dn OU=privilegedUser,OU=User,DC=company,DC=com

user-parameters user-object-class (memberOf=CN=switch-admins,OU=groups,OU=User,DC=company,DC=com)
```

Comment: You can also use group memebership to search, ismemeberof or memeberof attribute

Comment: @HamzaTahiri I tried to filter with "user-parameters user-object-class" see new second example. But was not yet successful.